# Is it possible to choose the stacking order of spans?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm starting a project with Twitter Bootstrap, and quite like the responsive css, making the spans stack on top of each other when the viewport gets smaller.

Given the following design: http://jsfiddle.net/kJp6J/1/

[image: Twitter responsive design]

Is it possible to choose which block will be stacked first on small screens? In my case, I'd like the block on the right to appear first, followed by the blocks on the left.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### HTML

Wrap your content with `.container`, put that big block on the first place, add `.pull-right` so it will appear right:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4 pull-right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/280x180">
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

When on mobile, place it where it should be with `float:none`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  [class*="span"].pull-right {
    float: none;
}
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJp6J/4/), I'll hope it works like you want it.