# Bootstrap Three Column Layout Stacking Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, responsive-design

I am using a 3 column layout in Bootstrap, with navigation, content & widgets on the right, but want the layout to stack as follows when the screen is in mobile view; navigation widgets and then content, please advise.

See the image for desired desktop & mobile layout order:

[image: http://www.nojomedia.com/images/3column-requirements.jpg]

Comment: Please include more info and at least an image of the layout you want.

Answer (score 6):

Put the block in the desired order for mobile. Then pull "widget" to the right:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 custom-nav"></div>
        <div class="span3 custom-widget pull-right"></div>
        <div class="span6 custom-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

When on mobile, reset the float:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    [class*="span"].pull-right {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

A few more things:

- I'm using `custom` prefix here to not run into Bootstrap's predefined `.nav` and `.content` classes.
- See how it works on [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUexV/2/).
- Check [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226859/is-it-possible-to-choose-the-stacking-order-of-spans/12227238#12227238) I've answered.
- Welcome to StackOverflow.