# Twitter Bootstrap Stacking Hierarchy

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am relatively new to using the Twitter Bootstrap 2, as I have only ever used Foundation. One thing that I cannot figure out how to do is to control stacking on smaller resolutions.

I have a three column layout I am using, two sidebars and the content area. Looks like so:

```
| Sidebar 1 |   |   Content     |   | Sidebar 2 |
```

On a smaller resolution however, I want the columns to stack like so:

```
|  Content  |
| Sidebar 1 |
| Sidebar 2 |
```

The only way I see to control such stacking in Bootstrap is by the use of pull-left or pull-right. Is there a better way, or is it even possible to do this with in Bootstrap?

Thanks!

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/q/12902555/1478467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a mechanism built into Bootstrap to control stacking order - elements will stack in the order they appear in the HTML.
If `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` are achieving the behavior you want, that's probably your best bet without resorting to JavaScript.

Comment: The problem is that they are not working. Unless im just being dense and cannot get them to place properly in desktop view. Is there a way to arrange the html:
CONTENT, SIDEBAR 1, SIDEBAR 2, but have the sidebar 1 float to the left of the content?

Comment: Can you put your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so I can test it out?

Answer (score 1):

I was just figuring out how to do the same thing, and here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 pull-right">Content</div>
        <div class="span3 pull-left">Sidebar 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">Sidebar 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used this same bag of "tricks" in my [Blueprint CSS Class](http://www.php-ease.com/classes/blueprint-css.html), but have just recently converted to Bootstrap and am converting things over.  Sorry, I'm a little late.